# change email address script + guidance

Tags: windows, powershell, exchange

We have a tiny company that is currently with @xxxx.com and the brand changed to @yyy.com

Can someone give me few guidance on steps to create a script that will change all of the @xxxx.com addresses to @yyyy.com and to preserve the first email address as alias?

This is contemplating that : email, distribution lists, shared mailboxes, user accounts and so on needs to be changed aswell.

Is there any impact? rollback can be made?

¿How can we properly proceed with this? Script? Maybe just a few step by step so we can look for it on how to perform but a few guidance with the script will be much more appreciated.

Thanks all!! happy new year!

Comment: You don't need a script, you need to change your email address policy.

Comment: Thanks @marsh-wiggle i'll take a look into it. We have contacted an expert exchange administrator that says it's not difficult. Only a tiny script that grabs all of the accounts and change it to the new email address and make the old email address as alias. But well, i'll have to dig into it because i don't know how to proceed.

Comment: If your Exchange expert is telling you that you need a script to do this then they're no Exchange expert. You only need to change your email address policy in Exchange to implement this change.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback @joeqwerty! :) question! : in the email address policy will take effect on each and every account that is xxx.com and will convert to yyyy.com ?? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It won't convert xxx.com to yyy.com. It will add yyy.com and set it as the primary SMTP address. xxx.com will remain.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to change the mailbox suffix name, it could achieve it by configuring Accepted Domains and Email Address Policies. Details are the following:

1. Configure new domain in accepted domain list in ECP. More details of Creating an Accepted Domain, you could see the link below:

**[Procedures for accepted domains in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/accepted-domains/accepted-domain-procedures?view=exchserver-2019)**

2. Create an email address policy to apply this new domain SMTP address into all mailboxes.

**[Procedures for email address policies in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/email-addresses-and-address-books/email-address-policies/eap-procedures?view=exchserver-2019#apply-email-address-policies-to-recipients)**